# openapi keyword "oneOf" with springdoc parameter "use-fqn=true" results error

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

**Environment**

```
springdoc-openapi-ui (1.6.12) with Kotlin
```

**Problem Details**

I"m implement simple RestController as follows:

```
@RestController
class DemoController {
    @PostMapping
    fun Post(@RequestBody body: Body) {
        TODO()
    }
}

@Schema(oneOf = [Body1::class, Body2::class, Body3::class])
interface Body

data class Body1(
    val demo: Int
) : Body

data class Body2(
    val demo: Int
) : Body

data class Body3(
    val demo: Int
) : Body
```

And I use springdoc parameter use-fqn on `application.properties` as follows:

```
springdoc.use-fqn=true
```

This time, Swagger-ui shows some errors.

```
Errors
Resolver error at paths./.post.requestBody.content.application/json.schema.oneOf.2.$ref
Could not resolve reference: undefined undefined
Resolver error at paths./.post.requestBody.content.application/json.schema.oneOf.1.$ref
Could not resolve reference: undefined undefined
Resolver error at paths./.post.requestBody.content.application/json.schema.oneOf.0.$ref
Could not resolve reference: undefined undefined
```

**Question**

Have I some mistakes? If so, how I fix this errors?

**Tried**

I tried to specify classes of `oneOf` keyword with FQN, but error occurred too.

**Expecting**

OpenAPI generates these schemas.

```
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "com.example.demo.Body": {
                "type": "object",
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "com.example.demo.Body1"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "com.example.demo.Body2"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "com.example.demo.Body3"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I thought schema reference must be `#/components/schemas/com.example.demo.BodyX`.